# How to change ion-input disabled opacity

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to change the opacity of an ion-input that is disabled and for now, nothing has worked.

The opacity is set in a native input inside my ion-input I guess that's why I can't access it.

This is what I tried so far :

```
ion-input[disabled] {
   background-color: var(--white);

   --opacity: 1 !important;
   opacity: 1 !important;
}
input[disabled], .native-input {
   opacity: 1 !important;
   --opacity: 1 !important;
```

}

Any ideas how to make this works ?

Thanks in advance.